# Remove function of BST in C#

Tags: c#, binary-search-tree

I am trying to write the remove function for BST in C#. I have some NUnit tests that need to pass. All of them pass except two. I have two scenarios for which the test fails.

I need to remove 10 for these two trees. But it's failing:

100, 10, 5

100, 10, 20

So I'm guessing my code doesn't splice the 10 out. And the error is in the RemoveNonRootNode method. And specifically with the "else if" statements that are looking at 1 child situation.

Here is my code. I appreciate some help!

```
public class BST
{
    private BSTNode m_top;

    private class BSTNode
    {
        private int m_data;
        private BSTNode m_left;
        private BSTNode m_right;

        public int Data
        {
            get { return m_data; }
            set { m_data = value; }
        }
        public BSTNode Left
        {
            get { return m_left; }
            set { m_left = value; }
        }
        public BSTNode Right
        {
            get { return m_right; }
            set { m_right = value; }
        }

        public BSTNode(int data)
        {
            m_data = data;
        }
    }

    public void AddValue(int v)
    {
        if (m_top == null)
        {
            m_top = new BSTNode(v);
        }
        else
        {
            BSTNode cur = m_top;
            while (true)
            {
                if (v < cur.Data)
                {
                    if (cur.Left == null)
                    {
                        cur.Left = new BSTNode(v);
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                        cur = cur.Left;
                }
                else if (v > cur.Data)
                {
                    if (cur.Right == null)
                    {
                        cur.Right = new BSTNode(v);
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                        cur = cur.Right;
                }
                else
                    throw new DuplicateValueException("Value " + v + " is already in the tree!");
            }
        }
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("=== Printing the tree ===");
        if (m_top == null)
            Console.WriteLine("Empty tree!");
        else
            PrintInternal(m_top);
    }
    private void PrintInternal(BSTNode cur)
    {
        if (cur.Left != null)
            PrintInternal(cur.Left);

        Console.WriteLine(cur.Data);

        if (cur.Right != null)
            PrintInternal(cur.Right);
    }

    public bool Find(int target)
    {
        return FindNode(target) != null;
    }

    private BSTNode FindNode(int target)
    {
        BSTNode cur = m_top;
        while (cur != null)
        {
            if (cur.Data == target)
                return cur;
            else if (target < cur.Data)
                cur = cur.Left;
            else if (target > cur.Data)
                cur = cur.Right;
        }

        return null;
    }


    public void Remove(int target)
    {
        // if the tree is empty:
        if (m_top == null)
            return;

        if (m_top.Data == target)
        {
            RemoveRootNode(target);
        }
        else
        {
            RemoveNonrootNode(target);
        }
    }

    private void RemoveNonrootNode(int target)
    {
        BSTNode cur = m_top;
        BSTNode parent = null;

        //First, find the target node that we need to remove
        // we'll have the 'parent' reference trail the cur pointer down the tree
        // so when we stop, cur is the node to remove, and parent is one above it.

        while (cur!= null && cur.Data != target)
        {
            parent = cur;
            if (target > cur.Data)
                cur = cur.Right;
            else
                cur = cur.Left;
        }

        // Next, we figure out which of the cases we're in

        // Case 1: The target node has no children
        if (cur.Left == null && cur.Right == null)
        {
            if (parent.Left==cur)
                parent.Left = null;
            else
                parent.Right = null;
        }
        // Case 2: The target node has 1 child
        // (You may want to split out the left vs. right child thing)
        else if (cur.Left == null)
        {
            BSTNode cur2 = cur;
            cur = cur.Right;
            cur2 = null;
            return;
        }
        else if (cur.Right == null)
        {
            BSTNode cur2 = cur;
            cur = cur.Right;
            cur2 = null;
            return;
        }

        // Case 3: The target node has 2 children

        BSTNode removee = FindAndRemoveNextSmallerValue(target, cur);
        cur.Data = removee.Data;
        return;
    }

    private void RemoveRootNode(int target)
    {
        // If we're here, it's because we're removing the top-most node (the 'root' node)

        // Case 1: Root has no children
        if (m_top.Left == null && m_top.Right == null)
        {
            m_top = null;            // Therefore, the tree is now empty
            return;
        }
        // Case 2: Root has 1 child
        else if (m_top.Left == null)
        {
            // 1 (right) child, OR zero children (right may also be null)
            m_top = m_top.Right; // Right is null or another node - either way is correct
            return;
        }
        else if (m_top.Right == null)
        {
            // If we're here, Left is not null, so there MUST be one (Left) Child
            m_top = m_top.Left;
            return;
        }
        // Case 3: Root has two children - this is where it gets interesting :)
        else
        {
            // 2 children - find (and remove) next smaller value
            // use that data to overwrite the current data.
            BSTNode removee = FindAndRemoveNextSmallerValue(target, m_top);
            m_top.Data = removee.Data;
            return;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method takes 1 step to the left, then walks as far to the right
    /// as possible.  Once that right-most node is found, it's removed & returned.
    /// Note that the node MAY be immediately to the left of the <B>startHere</B> 
    /// parameter, if startHere.Left.Right == null
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="smallerThanThis"></param>
    /// <param name="startHere"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private BSTNode FindAndRemoveNextSmallerValue(int smallerThanThis, BSTNode startHere)
    {
        BSTNode parent = startHere;
        BSTNode child = startHere.Left;

        if (child.Data == smallerThanThis)
        {
            child = null;
        }
        while (child.Right != null)
        {
            parent = child;
            child = child.Right;
        }

        parent = child;
        child = null;

        return parent;

    }

    // Given the value of a node, find (and remove) the predessor node in the tree
    // returns the value of the predecessor node, or Int32.MinValue if no such value was found
    public int TestFindAndRemoveNextSmallest(int sourceNode)
    {
        BSTNode startAt = this.FindNode(sourceNode);
        // sourceNode should == startAt.Data, unless startAt is null)
        BSTNode removed = FindAndRemoveNextSmallerValue(sourceNode, startAt);
        if (removed != null)
            return removed.Data;
        else
            return Int32.MinValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey there. I hope everything is fine. For everybody, their time is the most valuable. So please, can you let me know if this helped or not? I need to know that my spending time on this problem was not for nothing. Thanks.

Comment: @OguzOzgul yes! Thank you so much! That fixed the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first sight, there seems to be this bug:

```
            else if (cur.Left == null)
            {
                BSTNode cur2 = cur;
                cur = cur.Right;
                cur2 = null;
                return;
            }
            else if (cur.Right == null)
            {
                BSTNode cur2 = cur;
                // cur = cur.Right; // THIS SHOULD BE .Left, because .Right is NULL
                cur = cur.Left; // THIS IS THE FIX
                cur2 = null;
                return;
            }
```

But your actual problem is; updating the `cur` reference to something else does not change the pointer to the same object (`cur`) held by its parent. Actually, you did it right in Case 1, but somehow missed it in Case 2. Therefore; the full fix is: (only fixing the failing test. Promising no more).

```
            // Case 2: The target node has 1 child
            // (You may want to split out the left vs. right child thing)
            else if (cur.Left == null)
            {
                if (parent.Left == cur)
                {
                    parent.Left = cur.Right;
                }
                else
                {
                    parent.Right = cur.Right;
                }
                return;
            }
            else if (cur.Right == null)
            {
                if(parent.Left == cur)
                {
                    parent.Left = cur.Left;
                }
                else
                {
                    parent.Right = cur.Left;
                }
                return;
            }
```